# GDrive Upload not happening when moved to Staging url

Tags: wordpress, google-drive-api

I am using google-drive-sdk to upload a pdf file (dynamically generated in the php web app) to Gdrive.

**About my app**

On click of submit button the users are redirected to a THANKYOU page. At the background

- pdf file gets generated
- and this file will be uploaded to Gdrive account --(configured the client id & secret key for the app in Google Console) :

I am able to upload to the configured GDrive but first time to authenticate I run the url(redirect url given in Google Console) in browser(*say

> http://localhost:3422/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/mktProc/google-api-php-client/gDrive_access/pdf_results_upload.php

*) 
This takes me to *GDrve Request For Permission* page and prompts Allow\Deny Access and works perfectly in local development environment

**My Problem**
But for moving the code to Staging server, in Google Developer Console  I change the origin & return uri to Staging uri like the below.

> http://hyperAd.com/wp-content/plugins/mktProc/google-api-php-client/gDrive_access/pdf_results_upload.php

After this when I execute the app, it does not go to the *Google Request for Permission page* to prompt Allow\Deny. So no access token is received to proceed insert file to GDrive.

What is that I am missing here
or what mistake have I done here?

Comment: check that it's http not https. You should probably declare both in the API Console

Comment: its http only.
if I give https it throws an error --'improperly configured'

Would it be something like the Staging url is client secured and this happens?
or its something else?

Comment: Do you have any idea why this is happening?
Any pointers or clue this might occur?

Comment: Can anyone help me with this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause of the issue
There was a file access permission in the Staging server.

Giving the required permission in the staging server to the folder location where the token file (received from Google Request permission page) resides solved my issue.